# Vimperator is in the way of Github FuzzyFinder

Tags: firefox, github, vimperator, fuzzyfinder

I love using vimperator, it improves my browserflow by a ton however I recently discovered that whilst in a Github Repo, if you press t then you can commence a Github file fuzzyfinder. Herein lies the problem: I can't use it if I have vimperator on. I even set nnoremap t  but it still won't let me open the fuzzyfinder. Does anyone know a way to keep both?

Answer (score 1):

Use shift+esc to pause vimperator temporarily.